# Roaster: AddEnumConstant fails due to IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, jboss, roaster

I am creating an Enum with Roaster as follows:

```
import org.jboss.forge.roaster.Roaster;
import org.jboss.forge.roaster.model.source.JavaEnumSource;

rightsEnumSource = Roaster.create(JavaEnumSource.class);
rightsEnumSource.setPackage("io.enum").setName("RightsEnum");
```

I am getting an

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length
```

when executing:

```
rightsEnumSource.addEnumConstant("TEST.");
```

Please notice the Dot "." in "TEST.". Removing the dot

```
rightsEnumSource.addEnumConstant("TEST");
```

works fine.

I don't get why I get an exception.

Comment: check what those methods do. You're not nearly providing enough background or context. Either way, if the last char of that error message is also 0, somewhere you are trying to get the first element of an empty array/list/set/collection/..

Comment: addEnumConstant is a method provided by Roaster (https://javadoc.io/static/org.jboss.forge.roaster/roaster-api/2.19.4.Final/org/jboss/forge/roaster/model/source/JavaEnumSource.html#addEnumConstant()) so I expect it to work with any valid String provided

Comment: I don't know what Roaster is for, but a Java Enum's name cannot contain a dot (same as any other symbol name, like class names, field names, method names).